# Issue in solving the compilation error in xCode

Tags: iphone

HI all,

I have a issue while compiling the code. I got the code from svn. but it gives the following error :

error: syntax error at 'OTHER' token

error: syntax error at 'OTHER' token

error: syntax error at 'OTHER' token

error: syntax error at '#' token

error: syntax error before 'OBJC_STRING' token

error: syntax error before '}' token

fatal error: method definition not in @implementation context

I have checked the code, but i dint find any issues with the code.

I tried deleting the symbol "-" in front of the method definition and added it again. I have done "clean All Targets" but stil getting the same error on compilation .

Awaiting for your response ...

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq.

Comment: Mohammed, can you paste the code that is causing this error?

Comment: You have provided far too little information for us to figure out what's going wrong.  Please edit the question with the offending code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust me, when you can't find any issues in the code, but your compiler can, the compiler is right! Look again. In 20+ years of writing software professionally I found a compiler error *once*.

More practically, try commenting out code around the offending line. And post the code so we can all get a look. And check any header files you may be including, the error might be in there.